# Python - Wrong long mantissa in simple calculation

Tags: python

So, I new in python and i found a bug in my code. With this combination of variable (a,b,c) result of calculation (d) is wrong (0.8999999999999 instead 0.9). Other combination of variable calculate correct. I use python 3.6. What have I missed?

```
a = 0.3
b = 2
c = 0.6

d = a + (b - 1)*c
print(d)
```

Comment: That your program is correct and floating point number arithmetic isn't exact.

Comment: you can use round of
>> round(d,2)

Comment: You can try to round your result, but code is correct

Comment: Can I use something other than rounding in my situation?

Comment: go through with docs   https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Also see [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Many thanks, i will try